# How to store different lines of text file in different array elements in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file-io

How to store different lines of text file in different array elements in perl

E.g
Text File Contains

```
US
London
```

How to store US in array[0] and London in array[1]

Comment: Please clearify question

Comment: Just split your line on space. Or you want something else?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: there was a newline between those, now better formatted

Comment: @ysth - Thank you.  It does read better now.

Comment: This isn't complicated. [Try something.](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Put forth some effort.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fileName = 'text.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $fileName or die $!;
chomp( my @array = <$fh> );
close $fh;

print qq{\$array[0] contains "$array[0]"\n};
print qq{\$array[1] contains "$array[1]"};
```

Output:

```
$array[0] contains "US"
$array[1] contains "London"
```

Answer (score 3):

This will open a file and read each line into an array:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename;
chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
close $fh;
```

See [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once?) for more.

Comment: and `chomp(@lines)` to remove the newlines.

Comment: @ysth, thanks, I always forget to chomp :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@arr=();
open(KJ,"ur_file");
@arr=<KJ>;
close(KJ);
```